# Grouping alternative items with PySpark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, grouping

The sample of the dataset I am working on:

```py
# Creating the DataFrame
test =sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,2),(2,1),
                               (1,3),(2,3),
                               (3,2),(3,1),
                               (4,5),(5,4)],
                               ['cod_item','alter_cod'])
```

[image]

And it looks like this after grouping the equivalent items in lists:

```py
test.createOrReplaceTempView("teste")

teste = spark.sql("""select cod_item,
                  collect_list(alter_cod) as alternative_item 
                  from teste
                  group by cod_item""")
```

[image]

In the first column, I have certain items and in the second column, I have items that are equivalent. I would like, for each list, to have only one item that represents it.

I would like the final dataframe to look like this:

[image]

or

[image]

Where the items on the right are the items representing their respective equivalent items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `collect_list`, you should filter out rows where any alter_cod is bigger than cod_item. This method would work on strings too.

```py
test = (test
    .groupBy('cod_item')
    .agg(F.collect_list('alter_cod').alias('alter_cod'))
    .filter(F.forall('alter_cod', lambda x: x > F.col('cod_item')))
)

test.show()
# +--------+---------+
# |cod_item|alter_cod|
# +--------+---------+
# |       1|   [2, 3]|
# |       4|      [5]|
# +--------+---------+
```

Or add one line to your SQL:

```sql
select cod_item,
       collect_list(alter_cod) as alternative_item 
from teste
group by cod_item
having forall(alternative_item, x -> x > cod_item)
```